# really broken django migrations

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I get the following output when I run makemigrations and then migrate:

```
(roundwellenv) ruben@ruben-H81M-D2V:~/roundwell$ ./dev_migrations.sh 
No changes detected in apps 'contenttypes', 'parents', 'admin', 'tips', 'tutors', 'login', 'auth', 'quiz', 'sessions'
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, login, parents, quiz, sessions, tips, tutors
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying login.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying parents.0001_initial... OK
  Applying quiz.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying tips.0001_initial... OK
  Applying tutors.0001_initial... OK
(roundwellenv) ruben@ruben-H81M-D2V:~/roundwell$ python manage.py createsuperuser

You have 21 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, login, parents, quiz, sessions, tips, tutors.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

I know something is really wrong because even if I delete pycache content and the conent from migration folders and a clean sqlite3 db it actually doesn't find any migrations it needs to apply unless I specify the apps I would like to create migrations for. Any clue as to what could be causing this? I suspect it might be my custom login app, but once the migrations are done (like they are on the system here the site is actually run) the DB works fine.

Comment: Do a `manage.py showmigrations` and match the names of the migration modules with the one's applied. There is a table in the db which keeps a record of what migrations were applied and it seems like there is a mismatch there.

Comment: What is "dev_migrations.sh"? I suspect the bug lies in that script. In either case you probably need to post that for anyone to be able to answer your question.

Comment: @VinayPai That is is just `source env/bin/activate && python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate` so no that won't be the source unfortunatly

Comment: @ic_fl2 Just to rule out another possibility, have you specified the absolute path to your sqlite3 database in your settings file? It seems as if the migrate command and createsuperuser are operating on different databases. Does it say "no migrations to apply" if you run dev_migrations.sh twice in a row?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following, **while in your project folder:**

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

Then delete your sqlite DB, and try the migrations again.

> Make sure you are in your project folder, or else this command will break your Django download!